# check if audio system is in use

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

Is there a way to programatically check if the audio system is being exclusively used on the iPhone? If an app tries to use the audio system when a FaceTime or cellular phone call is active, it will get errors when trying to start up audio. I'd like to check if the audio system is being exclusively used before attempting to start up audio.

The app I'm working on is a VOIP type app. When there is an incoming call, I'd like to check if the audio system is usable before the call is allowed to be answered. I have tried CTCallCenter and it works for cell phone calls, but FaceTime calls don't show up in there.

Thanks,
Conway

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you initialize the audio input as soon as the incoming call is detected and start the queue once the user accepts the call?

Comment: This would work but it means a re-work of our audio code. For now, I'm just going to allow the call to be accepted and if there's an audio init failure, I'll hang up the call with an error message.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the interruption handling delegates in the audio session documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

You can set a flag in your app to prevent answering of your voice call if you are between beginInterruption and endInterruption methods.

Comment: There are a couple of problems with beginInterruption and endInterruption:

Comment: First problem: they don't come in pairs so at some point I last received a beginInterruption but did not receive and endInterruption; then my app thinks it's constantly interrupted. Second Problem: the interrupt mechanism does not distuingish between non-interruptable audio (cell phone and facetime calls) and interruptable audio (music player).

Comment: Sorry to hear you are still having troubles. If you find a nice solution then please post it. I'd be very interested to hear about it.

Comment: That link is no longer valid and this answer is obsolete.

Comment: I updated the link. `AVAudioSession` does not appear to be deprecated, so why is this obsolete? If there is a better method consider posting a new answer.